# axios put request doen't modify data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, axios

I have simple todo app and have checlbox inside that todo item. When I check it, I send put request to the firebase database specifying to the id of todo and status" true(so it will be check). But I got in response empty todo and checked todo also become empty

```
handleCheckTodo(id){
    const todo ={
      id,      
      status: true
    };
    axios.put('https://react-todo-app-XXXXX.firebaseio.com/todos.json', todo).then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);            
        }
    );
  }
```

Here is my todo structure:

```
const todo = {
      id: Math.random().toString(16).slice(2),
      name: todoName.value,
      body: todoDesription.value,
      status: false
    }
```

Create todo:

```
  addTodo(todoName, todoDesription) {
    console.log(todoName.value, todoDesription.value);
    const todo = {
      id: Math.random().toString(16).slice(2),
      name: todoName.value,
      body: todoDesription.value,
      status: false
    }    
    axios.post('https://react-todo-app-4b652.firebaseio.com/todos.json', todo).then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);            
        }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Are you able to do a put against this url in Postman with the same data? That's where I'd start.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where do `todoName.value` and `todoDescription.value` come from? Where you looking to make an object creator? `const todo = (id, name, body, status) => ({ ... });`

Comment: @Kyle Richardson check above addTodo methond